# Remove white loading page in Nuxt SPA mode

Tags: single-page-application, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt in SPA mode. Between loading different routes, the white loading screen appears.

[image]

When I use universal mode, it only has a white loading bar at the top, but when using SPA mode, the entire page becomes a white loading page.

Is there any way to avoid this with nuxt spa mode ?

Comment: add code for more detail, please. If you have loading property set in nuxt.config 
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/, please check

Comment: I noticed that I was not using nuxt links, I was using normal a tags. This caused a refresh on each page. It works fine when using the proper router links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake especially when you are using SPA mode, be sure to use nuxt links when routing between pages, else if you just use normal  tags, the page will refresh on each page.